# Images appear fine when I preview HTML page directly, but appear broken when same page is returned from flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web, flask

working on a small project, for which I have an HTML page. For now it is a static page, with everything hard-coded.

When I preview it locally, it appears fine. But when the same page is returned from flask using render_template, the image link appears broken.

Following is the structure of directory:

```
/
-server.py
--templates/
---org_dashboard.html
---img_avatar.png
```

Im attaching screenshots as well as code snippets from return function, and the corresponding HTML code.

Python/flask code:

```
@app.route('/org_dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def org_dashboard():
    return render_template('org_dashboard.html')
```

Corresponding HTML code with image path:

```
<div class="card-columns">
<div class="card">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
      <div class="container">
        <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
        <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When returned from localhost by flask. Notice the link appears broken:
[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP3ko.png)

When viewed directly by opening the HTML file. Image appears fine [Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjXzB.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your image path is implying something that is only true in a static local HTML file.

`src="img_avatar.png"` tells the browser that the file is located in the same folder as the current page.

You need to change this to a relative path like this: `src="/static/img_avatar.png"` and then move the file to the `/static` folder in your project root.

Flask makes the assumption that you will do this and automatically adds a static view that takes a path relative to the `project_root/static` directory and serves it.